# Swap column values with unique constraint in H2 database

Tags: sql, constraints, h2

Given is a simple database table `ENTITY` with a unique constraint on `POSITION`.

```
CREATE TABLE ENTITY (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    POSITION INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK_ENTITY_POSITION ON ENTITY (POSITION);
```

Furthermore given are more than two existing entities with unique positions.
Example:

```
INSERT INTO ENTITY (ID, POSITION) VALUES (1, 10);
INSERT INTO ENTITY (ID, POSITION) VALUES (2, 20);
INSERT INTO ENTITY (ID, POSITION) VALUES (3, 30);
```

A straight forward swap of the positions is not possible due to the unique constraint:

```
UPDATE ENTITY SET POSITION = 30 WHERE ID = 1;
UPDATE ENTITY SET POSITION = 10 WHERE ID = 2;
UPDATE ENTITY SET POSITION = 20 WHERE ID = 3;
```

How can the positions be swapped for an arbitrary number of entities with arbitrary positions, **within one transaction** on a H2 database.
[Temporary values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_(computer_science)#Using_a_temporary_variable) or temporary tables should not be used.
Note that H2 does not implement **deferred constraints** as of version 1.4.190.

Comment: You can try with `CASE` **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/410028)**. If it doesn't help another way is to change values to negative(still UNIQUE but with `-`)  and then update. Please let me know if it helps

Comment: @lad2025 that makes sense (though don't know how big it scales, and haven't actually tried it). You should write it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You  could use `CASE`:

```
UPDATE ENTITY
SET POSITION = CASE ID
                 WHEN 1 THEN 30
                 WHEN 2 THEN 10
                 WHEN 3 THEN 20
               END 
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/410028)**</kbd>

---

If all numbers are positive you could first change all numbers to negative and then update each value.

```
UPDATE ENTITY
SET POSITION = -POSITION
WHERE ID IN(1,2,3);

UPDATE ENTITY SET POSITION = 30 WHERE ID = 1;
UPDATE ENTITY SET POSITION = 10 WHERE ID = 2;
UPDATE ENTITY SET POSITION = 20 WHERE ID = 3;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo 2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/495654)**</kbd>

Comment: +1 for the negative numbers approach, I was always thinking about adding +1000 and negative is way better approach :)